# Why does Maven SCM plugin require connection/developerConnection?

Tags: maven, maven-scm

I am writing a plugin which copies some of the behaviour of the Maven SCM plugin and I was wondering:

Why can't the Maven SCM plugin just use the `remote "origin"` setting  from the `.git/config`?

Why does it require setting `<developerConnection>`/`<connection>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven committer here...

Maven and Maven SCM specifically need to fully abstract from the SCM system you use. It would be stupid to rely on internal details of a specific SCM. You provide both connection elements with a canonical format which helps us to determine a proper SCM provider at runtime.

Comment: BTW: I added a "connection correction" step in our build pipeline that checks, corrects and commits the actual connection/developerConnection in the POM.